# VBA Workbooks.open method from Cloud Storage

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

the code isn't working if i put an URL link, but it does working if it take from my hard disk. any advice? or should I use Microsoft Access?

```
Sub import_metering_actaris()
        Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    *****directory = "https://app.box.com/files/0/f/11396351585/1/f_95668743837"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "CS-FQC MV-001-01 Rev B (ACTARIS).xls")*****

    Do While fileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
            total = Workbooks("qc-generator.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
            after:=Workbooks("qc-generator.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
        Next sheet

        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

it gets error in directory & filename, any help would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: That's just not how HTTP works - you cannot use Dir() on an HTTP path.  Box has an API - you could use that.